# Entity SQL query with hierarchal relation

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-sql

I want to use Entity SQL to query the elements of some subtype in my Entity Model. For instance...

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM Persons AS c
WHERE c is of (Customer)
```

no problem meanwhile, but if I try the following query where `Active` is a property of Customer entity...

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM Persons AS c
WHERE c is of (Customer) AND c.Active == true
```

I got an error that state "**'Active' is not a member of type 'Person' in the currently loaded schemas.**"

What I'm missing from the above query? It is possible after all?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe you should replace the `==` with `=`?

It's still not clear since he's complaining on the property name, do you use a pluralization service, maybe you have to take care on the meaning of '`c`'.
This one is more likely the cause ([See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6b6d72f0-d894-4ae4-84f6-ec69e043e79a)).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using the following query:

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM OFTYPE (Persons, Customer) AS c
WHERE c.Active == true
```